# Spyder no console currently connected

Tags: python, console, spyder

I can run my script once with each Python console ("Python 1, Python 2, etc"), but after running, the console is unusable - I can't run or type anything into the console and get a return. When I try run the script again I get a message - 
"`No Python console is currently selected to run GameLoop.py. Please select or open a new Python console and try again.`"

If I open a new console, I can run the script again. But the new console has no memory of the variables created in the script.

I don't think this problem occured the first 2 times using Spyder. My version is Spyder 2.3.8 and I am running Python 2.7.
My console settings are set to "Execute in current IPython or Python console", but changing this setting to "dedicated" doesn't help.

How can I a console to continue being usable after running a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running a different version of Spyder & Python but was able to repro your issue. Make sure you always have an iPython console running, this will make sure you don't get this error. This will help even on re-opening spyder.

Comment: Thanks it works with the IPython console - its strange that I can't do the same with a python console

Answer (score 0):

Go to uninstall programmes>click on pythonxx(xx is version)>repair>yes

after repair procedure completed,Idle works fine.